# Parsing a nested JSON keys and getting the values in a CSV format

Tags: python, json

I have a nested JSON data like this of about 5000 records.

```
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "alert_type": "download",
                "severity_level": "med",
                "user": "10.1.1.16"
            },
            {
                "alert_type": "download",
                "severity_level": "low",
                "user": "10.2.1.18"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now , I need to parse this JSON and get only certain fields in a `CSV` format. Let's we would need `alert_type` & `user` in a CSV format.

I tried to parse this JSON dictionary:

```
>>> import json
>>> resp = '{"data":{"attributes":[{"alert_type":"download","severity_level":"med","user":"10.1.1.16"},{"alert_type":"download","severity_level":"low","user":"10.2.1.18"}]}}'
>>> user_dict = json.loads(resp)
>>> event_cnt = user_dict['data']['attributes']
>>> print event_cnt[0]['alert_type']
download
>>> print event_cnt[0]['user']
10.1.1.16
>>> print event_cnt[0]['alert_type'] + "," + event_cnt[0]['user']
download,10.1.1.16
>>>
```

How to get all the elements/`values` of a particular `keys` in a CSV format and in a single iteration ?

Output:

```
download,10.1.1.16
download,10.2.1.18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple list comprehension:

```
>>> jdict=json.loads(resp)
>>> ["{},{}".format(d["alert_type"],d["user"]) for d in jdict["data"]["attributes"]]
['download,10.1.1.16', 'download,10.2.1.18']
```

Which you can join for your desired output:

```
>>> li=["{},{}".format(d["alert_type"],d["user"]) for d in jdict["data"]["attributes"]]
>>> print '\n'.join(li)
download,10.1.1.16
download,10.2.1.18
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `{"data":{"attributes":` is a list, you can loop over it and print the values for desired keys (`d` is the user dict):

```
for item in d['data']['attributes']:
    print(item['alert_type'],',',item['user'], sep='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it somewhat data-driven like this:

```
import json

DESIRED_KEYS = 'alert_type', 'user'

resp = '''{ "data": {
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "alert_type": "download",
                        "severity_level": "med",
                        "user": "10.1.1.16"
                    },
                    {
                        "alert_type": "download",
                        "severity_level": "low",
                        "user": "10.2.1.18"
                    }
                ]
            }
          }
       '''

user_dict = json.loads(resp)

for attribute in user_dict['data']['attributes']:
    print(','.join(attribute[key] for key in DESIRED_KEYS))
```

To handle attributes that don't have all the keys, you could instead use this as the last line which will assign missing values a default value (such as a blank string as shown) instead of it causing an exception.

```
    print(','.join(attribute.get(key, '') for key in DESIRED_KEYS))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq), a one-line solution is straightforward:

```
$ jq -r '.data.attributes[] | [.alert_type, .user] | @csv' input.json
"download","10.1.1.16"
"download","10.2.1.18"
```

If you don't want the strings to be quoted, use `join(",")` instead of `@csv`

Comment: Thanks Peak. Using jq , yes its possible. I knew the way already but this should be on a pythonic way. I will be including this logic in a python function though.

Comment: pip install jq # For details, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jq ;
pip install pyjq # For details, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyjq